# Add custom property to panel

Tags: python, add-on

I created a custom property for my armature and I want to add it to my custom panel. If I want to add an object property to a panel I'll do it like this `layout.prop(object, "property")`. However this doesn't work for custom properties that I created. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Blender version 2.79.

Here is the panel code:

```
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_label = "MyPanel"
    bl_category = "MyPanel"

    def draw(self, context):
       layout = self.layout
       object = context.object

       layout.prop(object, "prop") #Custom property is called "prop"
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work, is there an error displayed on the console? What version of Blender are you using? Blender 2.8 you would implement your own tab differently.

Comment: @rjg The Blender version is 2.79. What doesn't work is the custom property isn't drawn on the panel. No error messages are displayed.

Comment: Can you show the code that declares the custom property?

Comment: @rjg I didn't define the custom property. I added it via the viewport.

Comment: @rjg Yes. How do I then display the property in the panel? I can reference the object like this `object = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]` and then write `layout.prop(object, "prop")`. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The custom property is not accessed as an attribute with the `.`, but through the name of the property.

```
bpy.data.objects["Armature"]["prop"]
```

Therefore the correct way of adding the property is:

```
layout.prop(bpy.data.objects["Armature"], '["prop"]')
```

You can add your custom property like this:

```
import bpy

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_label = "MyPanel"
    bl_category = "MyPanel"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(bpy.data.objects["Armature"], '["prop"]')


classes = (MyPanel,)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image: Screenshot UI]

Comment: Your code should check though whether an object called "Armature" actually exists and if it has a custom property called "prop".

Comment: Have you tested this out? Writing `layout.prop(bpy.data.objects["Armature"], '["prop"]')` doesn't work. The property doesn't get displayed.

Comment: Yes I've tested it. Have you checked that your armature and property are actually named like that?

Comment: I needed to reference the armature like this `bpy.data.armatures["Armature"]`. This fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LennyWhite in that case you've added the custom property in the armature tab instead of the object tab. Then you need to access it like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, assign "foobar" to an object:

```py
obj["foobar"] = 3
```

then in a panel draw() function:

```py
layout.prop(obj, f'["{bpy.utils.escape_identifier("foobar")}"]')
```

Also note:
**It appears the syntax is sensitive to the use of inner quoations - there have to be single double quotes `"` inside the bracket, single quotes `'` or triple double/single quotes `"""`/`'''` wont work**

---

*Previous answer by [Robert](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/74827/robert-g%c3%bctzkow) appears to be non-functioning in `Blender 3.6.2 Hash: e53e55951e7a`.
To get it to run without errors during registration, you have to remove the line:*

```py
bl_category = "MyPanel"
```

*and even then you get:*

```
rna_uiItemR: property not found: Object.["prop"]
```